# How to connect angular 2 app with .net core

Tags: node.js, angular, .net-core

As a beginner, I have installed angular cli, npm etc all the stuff and I am able to add some components to it. But It is incomplete until we use some backend. I am in .net background. Till now, I was using MVC but now I am migrating to .net core.

Well, Angular2 and .net core are two different apps. Now I have angular-2 app. How can I add this app in a .net core web application?

And usually we use CLI commands to add components and other things. So, when I will add angular app in .net core app, how can i be able to add components automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Feels like I need to add my 2c here. 
Angular2+ & Asp.Net Core 2+ is a perfect match for developing long lasting applications. 
Saying that, don't get fooled that Microsoft would be your friend here. Don't try to use VS build in Angular template or Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates package, as it will lead to you into rabbit hole of whole bunch of issues(just look at all questions about it on this site).
From my own experience of trying different approaches, create empty Asp.Net Web API project and create Angular app in it with Angular-CLI tool. From this point you can use angular-cli & dotnet cli for very enjoyable and productive experience.
Follow all steps in [this blog from Levi Fuller](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) and you'll get up and running in no time.

Answer (score 1):

You should build an API and then communicate with it from your Angular application.

Take a look at this tutorial, it covers the basics concepts:

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api*

Or in case that you want to integrate your application as a new project inside your solution, take a look at this one:

*https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/using-angular-2-with-asp-net-core*

Comment: Its for angular 1. I am trying for angular2.

Comment: I didn't noticed it. Added a link to a tutorial for Angular 2 instead

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Asp Core, your best bet is to use its spa templates [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

You can install it using

```
 dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

To start a new project with angular

```
dotnet new angular
```

Now the problem here is you want to integrate the angular cli with the asp core. I'm assuming that you want to use the angular cli commands to quickly generate a component. From a fresh angular project, look for angular-cli.json and copy paste it to the root of your asp project. Then update your package.json and add @angular/cli in the devDepencies like this

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.0"
  }
```

You can now run this command

```
ng g c my-component
```

Make sure that you run the npm install again and rerun the dotnet run / dotnet watch run if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create the ASP.Net core application, Create the Angular project using cli. Build and copy the angular project to www folder. You can add the components using the command prompt. Create the api in .Net core application and call it from angular